NodeJs fetch data by api-query-params
GitHub: https://github.com/khiemtongthong/projectSDN.git
Do the REST API (GET) endpoints
/book?page=1&limit=10&populate=comments&fields=comments.comment&commentSearch=excellent populate to match all comment text that contain the word "excellent" or "good".
This is my solution but not return data in Postman:
getBook: async (queryString) => {
    const page = parseInt(queryString.page) || 1; // Ensure page is a number
    const limit = parseInt(queryString.limit) || 10; // Default limit

    const { filter, population, projection } = aqp(queryString);

    delete filter.page;
    delete filter.limit; // Remove limit from filter

    if (queryString.minPrice) {
      filter.price = { $lt: parseFloat(queryString.minPrice) };
    }

    if (queryString.maxPrice) {
      filter.price = { $gt: parseFloat(queryString.maxPrice) };
    }

    // Comment search logic
    if (queryString.commentSearch) {
      const searchTerms = queryString.commentSearch.split(',');
      filter.comments = {
        $elemMatch: {
          comment: { $regex: searchTerms.join('|'), $options: 'i' } 
        }
      };
    }

    let offset = (page - 1) * limit;
    const result = await Book.find(filter)
      .populate(population)
      .skip(offset)
      .limit(limit)
      .select(projection)
      .exec();
    return result;
  },



that contain the word "excellent" or "good" why would good be at all relevant? you use the word excellent in the URL - good doesn't appear at all in the code

Thanks for your comment.
if I add word good with excellent  in the URL, it still does not return the result.
And I want to find a book with comments that are good or excellent.
